# Subquery returned more than 1 value error for getting specific value within columns

Tags: sql-server

i got stuck with a Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. What I'm trying to do is pull the specific quantity available per Size which is UserField1 column. Hoping to get some clarity over what I'm doing wrong. TIA!

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(InvMaster.AlternateKey1) AS 'Item Group', InvWarehouse.Warehouse,
        (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS 'S' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'SMALL'),
        (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS 'M' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'M'),
        (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS 'L' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'L'),
        (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS 'XL' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'XL'),
        (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS '2XL' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = '2XL')
    FROM InvMaster INNER JOIN InvWarehouse ON InvMaster.StockCode = InvWarehouse.StockCode
    WHERE InvMaster.ProductClass = 'FGUND'
    GROUP BY InvMaster.AlternateKey1, InvWarehouse.Warehouse
```

Comment: There is something called `Correlated Subquery` thats what you need !!

Comment: Hi Pradeep, haven't tried this yet but this looks like what i need now. Although I'm not sure yet how to implement the correlated subquery for this

Answer (score 0):

It's seem your InvMaster table has multiple rows with the same Size, try to add sum(QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) on subquery

Comment: Hi minkmd, I'm not trying to get the sum of (QtyOnHand-QtyAllocated). I want to pull all values associated to 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large' on separate columns. Or is there a way to dynamically do this? TIA!

Comment: @TerSiy you should remove InvWarehouse from sub-query on above post, this is unused and make your query run slowly. Sorry, I'm not enought reputation to comment on your post :)

Answer (score 0):

@TerSiy you can use subquery as table and using left join to query data, your sql should like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(InvMaster.AlternateKey1) AS 'Item Group', InvWarehouse.Warehouse , S.S, M.M, L.L


FROM InvMaster INNER JOIN InvWarehouse ON InvMaster.StockCode = InvWarehouse.StockCode 
left join (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS 'S', AlternateKey1 FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'SMALL') S
            ON InvMaster.AlternateKey1 = S.AlternateKey1
left join (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS 'M',AlternateKey1 FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'M') M
            ON InvMaster.AlternateKey1 = M.AlternateKey1
left join (SELECT (QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) AS 'L',AlternateKey1 FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'L') L
            ON InvMaster.AlternateKey1 = L.AlternateKey1
WHERE InvMaster.ProductClass = 'FGUND'
GROUP BY InvMaster.AlternateKey1, InvWarehouse.Warehouse
```

Comment: Hi minkmd, tried this and the query is taking a long time. But if i try to target a specific InvMaster.AlternateKey1 i get no results

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output rows as column in this case the UserField1, try to use pivot. Hope this helps. SQL does not allow column name starting with a number, you may want to comment out the 2XL column.

```
    SELECT InvMaster.AlternateKey1 AS 'Item Group', 
            InvWarehouse.Warehouse,
            S AS 'SMALL',
            M,
            L,
            XL,
            2XL
    FROM (
        SELECT InvMaster.AlternateKey1, 
                InvWarehouse.Warehouse,
                UserField1
        FROM InvMaster im
        INNER JOIN InvWarehouse  iw
            ON im.StockCode = iw.StockCode
        WHERE im.ProductClass = 'FGUND') up
        PIVOT (SUM(QtyOnHand - QtyAllocated) FOR UserField1 IN (S, M, L, XL, 2XL)) AS pvt
    ORDER BY InvMaster.AlternateKey1, InvWarehouse.Warehouse
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM In your Query Like below :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(InvMaster.AlternateKey1) AS 'Item Group', InvWarehouse.Warehouse,
        (SELECT sum(QtyOnHand) - sum(QtyAllocated) AS 'S' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'SMALL'),
        (SELECT sum(QtyOnHand) - sum(QtyAllocated) AS 'M' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'M'),
        (SELECT sum(QtyOnHand) - sum(QtyAllocated) AS 'L' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'L'),
        (SELECT sum(QtyOnHand) - sum(QtyAllocated) AS 'XL' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = 'XL'),
        (SELECT sum(QtyOnHand) - sum(QtyAllocated) AS '2XL' FROM InvMaster WHERE UserField1 = '2XL')
    FROM InvMaster INNER JOIN InvWarehouse ON InvMaster.StockCode = InvWarehouse.StockCode
    WHERE InvMaster.ProductClass = 'FGUND'
    GROUP BY InvMaster.AlternateKey1, InvWarehouse.Warehouse
```

Comment: Hi Navneet, seems I can't use Top 1 since I will need all records with Size Small, Medium, Large, XL and so on on separate columns.